# Dropdownmenu are not visible on Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap 3.0.3 and have created with nav nav-pills-justified a nav-section. this also includes dropdown. Unfortunately, the dropdown menu does not show up or are not visible.

Under [http://jsbin.com/ujODovO/1/edit?html, css, js, output](http://jsbin.com/ujODovO/1/edit?html,%20css,%20js,%20output) are my work.

I hope i get some solution to fix this

Comment: I does show up for me. maybe you need to click `output` link to see it? :)

Comment: This isn't a complete answer because I can't really tell what the original design intent is, but I can say by looking at it briefly that the overflow:hidden property on .mnav li is currently hiding the dropdown and needs to be removed. Removing it will probably break floats on your layout, so I'd recommend using clearfix to contain them. I'd also recommend refactoring this line: * html .mnav ul{overflow:hidden}. Why not just change the selector to .mnav ul?

Comment: @Morpheus  you are right - with forefox it runs but not in chrome, IE and opera it doesn't run. Do you know an fix for this?

Comment: @ccnokes could you show me what you mean because at the moment i did not understand what you mean

Comment: The overflow:hidden is deleted and it shows horrible http://jsbin.com/ujODovO/5/edit?html,css,js,output